# How to find number of Sundays in a given year (ex: input_year = 1996) and also the dates of those Sundays

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle11g

How to find number of Sundays in a given year in Oracle SQL.

Input: `1996`

Expected output:

```
<date-of-sunday-1>
<date-of-sunday-2>
.............
.............
<date-of-sunday-n>
<count-of-no-of-sundays-in-that-year>
```

Comment: Why did you tag your question with Java and MySQL? If you want to do that with Java, why do you thing a database is needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how to fetch *Sundays*:

```
SQL> with the_whole_year as
  2    (select trunc(to_date(&&par_year, 'yyyy'), 'yyyy') + level - 1 c_date,
  3            to_char(trunc(to_date(&&par_year, 'yyyy'), 'yyyy') + level - 1, 'fmday') c_day
  4     from dual
  5     connect by level <= add_months(trunc(to_date(&&par_year, 'yyyy'), 'yyyy'), 12) -
  6                         trunc(to_date(&&par_year, 'yyyy'), 'yyyy')
  7    )
  8  select c_date
  9  from the_whole_year
 10  where c_day = 'sunday';

C_DATE
----------
07.01.1996
14.01.1996
21.01.1996
28.01.1996
04.02.1996
11.02.1996
<snip>
```

I suppose you'll be able to count them yourself.

---

**[EDIT: a function that does the counting]**

```
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_count_of_sundays (par_year IN NUMBER)
  2     RETURN NUMBER
  3  IS
  4     retval   NUMBER;
  5  BEGIN
  6     WITH the_whole_year
  7          AS (    SELECT TRUNC (TO_DATE (par_year, 'yyyy'), 'yyyy') + LEVEL - 1
  8                            c_date,
  9                         TO_CHAR (
 10                            TRUNC (TO_DATE (par_year, 'yyyy'), 'yyyy') + LEVEL - 1,
 11                            'fmday')
 12                            c_day
 13                    FROM DUAL
 14              CONNECT BY LEVEL <=
 15                              ADD_MONTHS (
 16                                 TRUNC (TO_DATE (par_year, 'yyyy'), 'yyyy'),
 17                                 12)
 18                            - TRUNC (TO_DATE (par_year, 'yyyy'), 'yyyy'))
 19     SELECT COUNT (*)
 20       INTO retval
 21       FROM the_whole_year
 22      WHERE c_day = 'sunday';
 23
 24     RETURN retval;
 25  END;
 26  /

Function created.

SQL> select f_count_of_sundays(1996) from dual;

F_COUNT_OF_SUNDAYS(1996)
------------------------
                      52

SQL>
```

Comment: My PL/SQL block contains.
1) First I entered the year.
2) Found the first date and last date of that year.
3) Started loop to find whether first_day is Sunday and went on incrementing it till the last date of that year.
4) Counted the no:of sundays.
Note: BUT ITS NOT WORKING :(

Comment: I can't debug code I can't see. Anyway, you don't need a loop - I showed you a way to do that. I edited my message and added a function. Have a look.